# I am using windows7 but for ruby version 1.93 autoit call not working

Tags: ruby, watir, autoit

```
$ie.link(:text,"Revoke").click_no_wait
$autoit.WinWaitActive("[Class:#32770]")
result =$autoit.ControlClick("[Class:#32770]","","Button1")
```

I am using above code to click on OK on confimration popup
But its not working for New ruby version 1.93

Is there any other way to click on OK for confirmation popup?

Comment: When i am running the script on click_no_wait it pauses the script & script wait for popup to open but popup not opening , If user directly click on button it runs the autoit script so i think its click_no_wait problem, its unable to initialize call

Comment: There are many suggestions for popup handling. http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups

Comment: Are you saying it does not work with windows 7, ruby 1.9.3, or for combination of both? Or are you saying it just does not work and you have no idea why?

Comment: @ Dave McNulla - I checked ' wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups ' this link before i go for autoit its not working with my case. Currently on XP & Ruby 1.92 above code works.

Comment: @Filipin- I am asking for Windows 7 with ruby 1.93 & autoit current version  I tried diffent commands for Handling JS popup but in my case its not working as my Project work on IE only so Need solution for IE. And i am sure its not working in my case

Comment: Watir-webdriver has a different way to deal with popups, so potentially it might work were watir fails.  And it would give you cross browser support, so might be worth looking at depending on how valuable that would be compared to effort of updating scripts

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for Windows7 we have to register AutoItX3_x64.dll
To the system

Below is the command to register the dll in the system
You will find AutoItX3_x64.dll in C:\program file\autoit
copy paste that dll in c:\windows\sysWOW64\

& run below command in command prompt

c:\windows\sysWOW64\regsvr32.exe c:\windows\sysWOW64\AutoItX3_x64.dll